# how to choose files always from my account using dropbox drop-in app?

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

I'm trying to learn DropBox API, I started learning using of creating Drop-in chooser APP. I created app and it works success, but before I choose the file, it needs to login on dropbox system. I want to set my app on my account, so for every user when they open my app, I want to give them possibility to choose files from my dropbox account. I want to create app and choose files without loggining on dropbox. I hope you understand what I mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Drop-ins are part of the Dropbox web site, and are built to show the user their own accounts, so it's not possible to use the Drop-ins with a single pre-defined account for all users.

The [Dropbox Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core) was also designed with the intention that each user would link their own Dropbox account, in order to interact with their own files. However, it is technically possible to connect to just one account. The SDKs don't offer explicit support for it and we don't recommend doing so, for various technical and security reasons.

However if you did want to go this route, instead of kicking off the authorization flow, you would manually use an existing access token for your app. (Just be careful not to revoke it, e.g. via https://www.dropbox.com/account/security .)

Comment: Hey Greg, thank you so much for your answer. I thought, that it was possible, but there is no problem. I'll search other ways to solve this problem without against the dropbox security.